# nginx gives 504 error after 500 requests

Tags: nginx, timeout

I'm pretty new to using nginx and I'm having an issue where after requesting 500 pages from nginx running locally on my computer I start getting 504 Gateway Timeout error.

My nginx.conf file looks like this

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    proxy_buffer_size   128k;
    proxy_buffers   4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        charset utf-8;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.php index.htm;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            root           html;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 5s;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

    server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     local-testserver;
    error_log       logs/local-testserver.error.log;
    access_log      logs/local-testserver.access.log;
    keepalive_timeout  1s;

    location / {
        root        C:/Code/PHP/TestServer;
        index       index.php;
    }



        location ~ \.php$ {
            root            C:/Code/PHP/TestServer;
            fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index   index.php;
        }

    }
}
```

And index.php in TestServer/ just contains

```
<?php
    echo "hi";
?>
```

I'm testing this with the URLRequest class in AS3, but I actually tried manually sending 500 requests to see if that made a difference and in both cases the 501st request got a 504 error. Restarting the server allows me to make another 500 requests.

Any ideas on what might be happening or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this isn't an nginx issue at all but a FastCGI one. Setting PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=0 as an environment variable before starting FastCGI should allow any number of requests.